# Jquery .on() Vue.js rendered raw HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Is it possible to use `.on()` jquery bindings on raw HTML rendered by Vue.js? For example, the returned comment body will contain a link (`<a data-post="url">`) that the jquery script binds to:

```
<div id="comments">
    <div v-for="comment in comments">
        @{{{ comment.body }}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Vue Script:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#comments',
    data: {
        comments: []
    },
    ready : function () {
        this.fetch();
    },
    methods : {
        fetch: function () {
            this.$http.get('api/comments', function (comments) {
                this.$set('comments', comments);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Jquery Script:

```
$('[data-post]').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is this possible? The comments display correctly, though it seems that the jquery bindings don't take effect?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think ideally you'd set it up so Vue handles the display of the link.  Returning HTML from your controller is making your view and your controller more coupled than you want.  If your controller just returned the `href` attribute, you could make Vue generate the `a` tag and then handle clicks using a Vue method.

Comment: @Jeff That's true, but I'm having difficulty combining Laravel policies with client side display, so I'm using this as a band-aid at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding on the `body` instead of the `data-post` attribute allowed me to accomplish this:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-post]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Instead of

$('[data-post]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Returning raw JSON HTML from an ajax request and rendering it in Vue seems to work just fine.